# What is Algorithmic Game Theory?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, game-theory

Can someone give a good explanation + examples of algorithmic game theory? I read the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_game_theory) and found a stanford course on it from 2012, though its still not clear for me what the use cases are.

Also, is it still relevant today?

Comment: Could you provide a link (or a reference) to the Stanford course?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin The OP probably referred to http://theory.stanford.edu/~tim/f13/f13.html

Comment: @J.-E.Pin correct, that is the one I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algorithmic game theory is a very active research area today with research appearing in conferences such as Economics and Computation (EC), Web and Internet Economics (WINE), and various theoretical computer science and artificial intelligence venues; as well as journals in economics, computer science, and operations research. AGT is tricky to pin down because it can range from pure economics questions to purely algorithmic or computational questions, so in the end it is a very broad area.

It sounds like you are asking about use cases and relevance to practical applications today (not research areas, which are maybe well covered already). Many examples can be found in tech company applications. There are advertising auctions run by Google, Facebook, and others. The design of these, including algorithmic considerations, are heavily studied in AGT. The recent [FCC Spectrum auction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_reallocation#Broadcast_incentive_auction) heavily relied on both algorithmic and game-theoretic considerations, as it is a tricky constraint-satisfaction problem to allocate spectrum to wireless providers without interference. Design of other platforms like hotel/flight search, gig economy, AirBnB, Lyft/Uber, Amazon, eBay, etc. all potentially use principles or ideas from AGT. Prediction markets are used internally at companies and for political events. You may consider a lot of recent cryptocurrency questions to fall roughly in the AGT realm as well, although academic research there is still sparse.